# How should I be adding a GridLayout of JButtons below a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

So, I'm working on a project for my Java class. The objective is to create a basic GUI program that displays Hello World as a string and provides four buttons for manipulating the string. Something like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uczwB.png)

[image]

I haven't even gotten to the manipulation part of the program yet as I can't seem to get my window formatted correctly no matter what I try.

I am able to get my four buttons to display, but everything I have thrown at it to get the JLabel to display Hello World above the buttons is utterly failing me.

This seems so very simple, so I'm afraid there's something obvious I'm missing.  I've scoured the web for a week and found lots of info on how to do this in theory, so from what I can understand, this must be a problem with my syntax.

To date I have not found an implementation that does anything along the lines of what I am needing to do. This is driving me crazy and I'm going to go past my due date either way. I just have to have an answer! Thank you so much to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Here is my code in its current form. I felt like I was getting close with this, but it returns an exception to the console when running. Again, all help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorld
{   
    private JButton uppercaseButton;
    private JButton lowercaseButton;
    private JButton phraseButton;
    private JButton resetButton;

    private JPanel grid;

    public JPanel ButtonGrid()
    {

        JPanel grid = new JPanel();

        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        uppercaseButton = new JButton("Uppercase");
        lowercaseButton = new JButton("Lowercase");
        phraseButton = new JButton("New Phrase");
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");     

        grid.add(uppercaseButton);
        grid.add(lowercaseButton);
        grid.add(phraseButton);
        grid.add(resetButton);

        return grid;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("THIS IS MY TITLE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("HELLO WORLD");
        lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        ButtonGrid b = new ButtonGrid();
        b.setVisible( true );
        b.setSize( 300, 200 );
        frame.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: How about using a GridLayout, which has 1 column and 2 rows, then add the JLabel. After that add another JPanel and set the layout manager of that to another GridLayout of 2x2. Now you just need to add the 4 Buttons to the JPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ButtonGrid b = new ButtonGrid();
```

ButtonGrid is not a class, it is a method of the HelloWorld class that returns an instance of a `JPanel`.

So you need to create an instance of the `HelloWorld` class so you can invoke the method:

```
HelloWord hw = new HelloWorld()
JPanel b = hw.ButtonGrid();
```

And since "buttonGrid" is a method is should NOT start with an  upper case character so you need to rename the method and then use:

```
//ButtonGrid b = new ButtonGrid();
HelloWord hw = new HelloWorld()
JPanel b = hw.buttonGrid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both suggestions for pointing me in the right direction!

What ended up working was basically what redxef suggested first. Camickr then helped me further because I was thinking about my methods all wrong. By combining both of those JPanels into the first method and renaming it HelloWorld, I was able to clean up some other issues I was having as well.

I'm happy to report that as a result, the project was finished and turned in with about an hour to spare. Again, thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad the suggestions helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.